# What does "dat 14s drop" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, internet

I've found this expression on the Natural Selection 2 fanpage: https://www.facebook.com/NaturalSelection2/posts/10152301360338105

Comment: Can you please add a bit more content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's just mentioning to notice the soldier falling at 00:14 in the video.

"Dat" should means "that", I've only found this word in colloquial Internet language (such as in "dat ass").

Comment: I liked your answer :) please double "L" this word : "colloquial" .

Comment: It actually doesn't really come from the internet and is much older, and has been very popular in regions of the American South for decades.

Comment: @JDong That's correct, of course, but there is a particular slang usage that isn't limited to a particular region, and is used by people who would never otherwise pronounce *that* like *dat*.  It seems fine to me to mention how it's used today as slang online.

Comment: @JDong "Dat" is also common in the Caribbean.

Answer (score 11):

jinawee is *almost* correct.

Rather than referring to a soldier falling down, this is referring a bass drop at 00:14 in the video, where the background music went "wub-wub-wub" for a moment.

> [In dubstep, the drop involves a heavy full bass line and commonly a "wobble" or "vowel" bass accompanied by a strong shuffling beat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_drop)

To add a bit more detail: Each time I've seen the colloquial Internet usage of "dat `___`", the `___` has always been a good/desirable example of its-sort-of-thing.

Comment: I never knew this usage before. It's neat to have a memorable handle for something like that!

Comment: I only learned about it by asking a friend to explain the joke in the last sentence of "[What if a rainstorm dropped all of its water in a single giant drop?](https://what-if.xkcd.com/12/)"